# SqlDataReader Performance List<string[]> or List<object[]>

Tags: c#, performance, sqldatareader

I have been experimenting with ways to read data from a SQL server as quickly as possible and I came across an interesting discovery. If I read the data into a `List<object[]>` instead of a `List<string[]>`, performance increases by more than double.

I suspect this is due to not having to call the `ToString()` method on the fields, but I always thought that using objects had a negative impact on performance.

Is there any reason to not use a list of object arrays instead of string arrays?

EDIT: One thought I just had was the storage size of this data. Will storing the data in object arrays take more room than as strings?

Here is my test code:

```
private void executeSqlObject()
    {
        List<object[]> list = new List<object[]>();

        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(_cnnString))
        {
            cnn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from test_table", cnn);

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            int fieldCount = reader.FieldCount;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                object[] row = new object[fieldCount];

                for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
                {
                    row[i] = reader[i];
                }
                list.Add(row);
            }
        }
    }

    private void executeSqlString()
    {
        List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();

        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(_cnnString))
        {
            cnn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from test_table", cnn);

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            int fieldCount = reader.FieldCount;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string[] row = new string[fieldCount];

                for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
                {
                    row[i] = reader[i].ToString();
                }
                list.Add(row);
            }
        }
    }

    private void runTests()
    {
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            watch.Start();
            executeSqlObject();
            Debug.WriteLine("Object Time: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
            watch.Reset();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            watch.Start();
            executeSqlString();
            Debug.WriteLine("String Time: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
            watch.Reset();
        }
    }
```

And the results:

```
Object Time: 879
Object Time: 812
Object Time: 825
Object Time: 882
Object Time: 880
Object Time: 905
Object Time: 815
Object Time: 799
Object Time: 823
Object Time: 817
Average: 844

String Time: 1819
String Time: 1790
String Time: 1787
String Time: 1856
String Time: 1795
String Time: 1731
String Time: 1792
String Time: 1799
String Time: 1762
String Time: 1869
Average: 1800
```

Comment: Can't argue with results. You should also wrap your readers (and commands too) in using statements as well because those can leak memory.

Comment: There has to be something wrong with the test... Compared to reading the data from the database, making the string type check *should* be negligigle.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it any different if you simply cast the reader value to a string (`row[i] = (string)reader[i];`) instead of calling `ToString()` on it, or instead, using the built-in `SqlDataReader.GetString()` method to retrieve the value (`row[i] = reader.GetString(i);`)? (Aassuming all column values are strings.)

Comment: @Guffa it is not stated that this is just a type-check; this is most likely a *conversion* to formatted form, from other data types. Which will, undoubtedly, add work.

Comment: @Guaffa - Exactly as Marc said, it is the conversion from non-string types that causes the problem - I noticed similar performance to the object[] test when I used reader[i] as string.

Comment: @ChandlerPelhams but I imagine you got a lot of `null` values, which isn't particularly helpful to you ;p

Comment: What kind of data is it you read? If you read strings this is not true data. If its something else then ToString() and the additional data size will of course screw stuff up..

Comment: If you are converting from some other type to string, then you are either doing it wrong from the beginning, or any time won by avoiding the conversion will just move to the part of the code where you need to convert them to strings to display them.

Comment: Eventually the results will be displayed in a virtual Datagrid - which will convert the results into strings when it displays them in the cells. This would type-conversion to occur only when the CellValueNeeded event gets triggered rather than all at once when the query is being executed.

Comment: @ChandlerPelhams Did you ever benchmark "as string"  or straight type casting?  If so what were the results as compared to using ToString()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`object` only adds overhead if you are causing *additional* boxing. And even then, this impact is fairly minimal. In your case, `reader[i]` **always** returns `object`. You already have it as `object`, no matter whether that is a reference to a string, or an int, etc. Of **course** calling `.ToString()` adds overhead; in most cases (int, DateTime, etc) this involves both formatting code *and* the allocation of one (or more) extra string. By changing to `string` you are **changing the data** (for the worse, IMO - for example, you can no longer do correct sorts on dates, for example) and adding overhead. The edge case here is if all the columns are already actually strings - in which case you just add a few virtual method calls (but no extra real work).

For info, if you are after raw performance, I thoroughly recommend looking at the micro-ORMs such as dapper. They are heavily optimised, but avoid the weight of "full" ORMs. For example, in dapper:

```
var myData = connection.Query<TypedObject>("select * from test_table").ToList();
```

will, I expect, perform very comparably while giving you strongly typed object data.

Comment: Marc, thanks for the good info. In reference to the micro-ORM solution, wouldn't this solution require me to know the dataset that I am retrieving before executing the query? I need this application to be agnostic of the data it is retrieving

Comment: @ChandlerPelhams that was not clear from the question ;p Assuming you can't pass a `T` down via generics (in most applications, *some* part of the caller knows what the data looks like), then indeed something more generic such as `object[]` or, as "lowds" notes, `DataTable`, may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any reason to not use a list of object arrays instead of string arrays?

It would depend on what you wanted to do with the retrieved values after you got them into the arrays, if you're happy to treat each value as an object then having a list of objects is fine, but if you want to treat them as strings then at some point you're going to have to convert/cast the object back to a string so you're going to incur the cost somewhere.

As Cory mentioned if you're reading the value as a string from the SqlDataReader you should test using the GetString(int) method rather than calling ToString() on the value, and use this as the benchmark.

Alternatively, rather than use arrays you can read the values into a DataSet which may prove easier to work with afterwards.

End of the day, what's the best depends a lot on how you want to use the results after retrieving them from the database.

Comment: lol, usability of DataSet vs List of arrays... think that's a topic for another SO question :)

Comment: In the case given, it seems (comments) that the code may not know the layout, in which case I have to note that DataTable may indeed be appropriate.